# What do the totals do in a highcharts rose chart?

Tags: highcharts

In the below code there is a section for totals. What does the totals do - I dont see them displayed on the chart? Unless I'm reading it wrong.

```
<tr nowrap>
        <td class="totals">Total</td>
        <td class="totals">25.53</td>
        <td class="totals">44.54</td>
        <td class="totals">15.07</td>
        <td class="totals">8.52</td>
        <td class="totals">4.31</td>
        <td class="totals">1.81</td>
        <td class="totals">0.23</td>
        <td class="totals">&nbsp;</td>
```

Here is the link to the code:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-wind-rose/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't displayed, it's use case whe you have more columns/rows in table than you want ot display:

```
    data: {
        table: 'freq',
        startRow: 1,
        endRow: 17,
        endColumn: 7 // set to 8 to display total
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ELAug/